# Put indeterminate spinner in ActionBar

Tags: android

In my action bar I have 2 different icons that load different data. I want to remove my popup dialog's when the data is loading and replace the icon in the action bar with an indeterminate spinner whilst the data's loading, and then go back to the original icon.

What will be the best way of doing this? Will I need a custom action bar layout? At the moment my action bar icon's are just set up from a XML file

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/clear_stored_data"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@drawable/content_discard"
    android:showAsAction="never" />

<item android:id="@+id/refresh_list"
    android:title="@string/refresh_list"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@drawable/navigation_refresh"
    android:showAsAction="always" />

<item android:id="@+id/search_using_location"
    android:title="@string/search_using_current_location_short"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@drawable/device_access_location_found"
    android:showAsAction="always" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the [RefreshActionItem](https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/RefreshActionItem) project on Github. It's a third party component that does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I've just got ABS set up in my project now, once I've checked it all works I'll take a look at that, but it does sound like that's what I'm after.

Comment: Even though RefreshActionItem looks perfectly okay I ended up using http://www.michenux.net/android-refresh-item-action-bar-circular-progressbar-578.html

Comment: That is probably what RefreshActionItem is doing anyway. I'm glad you got it working the way you like.